# How make Safari open XML file instead of downloading it

Tags: safari, xml

I'm on MacOS Sierra.  When I click on a link to XML file, Safari downloads it.  Instead I want to view the XML right in the browser.  Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Safari seems to show XML files as XML, at least for me. Could you try viewing [this](http://mesu.apple.com/assets/com_apple_MobileAsset_SoftwareUpdate/com_apple_MobileAsset_SoftwareUpdate.xml)?

Comment: I was able to view it!  Oddly, when I try to open any maven-metadata.xml in my company's internal Artifactory repo, it promptly downloads it.

Answer (score 3):

Safari *does* open XML files, unless the server specifically tells Safari to download the file.
It's currently not possible to override the server's instruction to download instead of view.

Comment: Honestly that's a better question. "Can you override download headers in safari?".

Answer (score 2):

Just faced this problem while trying to download an XML instead of opening it in Safari.

Turned out you just have to **File** > **Save As** > **Source Code**
For me, it was saved as pure XML.